# accessing error while submitting spark job from local to spark cluster which is located on server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to run a simple spark program in my eclipse ide, and i am using spark master url but i am getting a error again and again.
Please find the error which i am facing

```
2019-11-20 11:49:58 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 9 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-11-20 11:49:58 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 9 requested
2019-11-20 11:49:58 INFO  KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
2019-11-20 11:50:01 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:06 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:07 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 10 requested
2019-11-20 11:50:07 INFO  KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 10
2019-11-20 11:50:07 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 10 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-11-20 11:50:11 WARN  TaskSchedulerImpl:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-11-20 11:50:11 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:13 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:17 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 11 requested
2019-11-20 11:50:17 INFO  KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 11
2019-11-20 11:50:17 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 11 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-11-20 11:50:19 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:23 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:25 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 12 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-11-20 11:50:25 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 12 requested
2019-11-20 11:50:25 INFO  KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 12
2019-11-20 11:50:26 WARN  TaskSchedulerImpl:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-11-20 11:50:28 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:32 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2019-11-20 11:50:34 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 13 requested
2019-11-20 11:50:34 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 13 from BlockManagerMaster.
2019-11-20 11:50:34 INFO  KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 13"
``
Please find the my spark conf:
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparksetuptest").setMaster("k8s://http://10.90.xx.xx:xx").set("spark.cores.max", "1").set("spark.driver.host", "10.95.xx.xx").set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","false").set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","false")
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
      .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
      .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.local.ip","10.90.xx.xx")
      .set("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "shreet007/spark")
      .set("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster")
      .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores","2")
      .set("spark.executor.instances", "3")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","2g")
      .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "1")
      .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "3")
```

Comment: Most probably your cluster doesn't have enough resources to schedule executors. Try to check the Kubernetes cluster nodes capacity and verify that you request feasible CPU and memory for Executors. Some details about your environment and Spark configs could help to move further.

Comment: thanks for the reply and we are using spark on kubernetes with 3 node cluster and 8 cores 16gb each, and we are using image of spark 2.4.4 .

Comment: Please find my code:                                                                                              val mysql_df = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", URL)
  .option("dbtable","table1")
  .option("user", "user")
  .option("password", "passw9rd")
  .load()
  
     mysql_df.show()

Comment: Ahh, sorry for confusing, I missed that you're working from the IDE. To make it work you need to set `("spark.submit.deployMode","client")`. But it will work for you only if your IDE environment has network access to the Kubernetes private virtual network and vice-verse, so that Driver process running on your IDE could communicate with the remote Executor processes in Kubernetes Pods. Your case would be similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635732/cant-create-spark-session-using-yarn-inside-kubernetes-pod/58641310#58641310).

Comment: Thank you very much Aliaksandr. It is really helpful for me